# Getting "Module not found" error

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

When I run my angular 2 project using

> npm start

I had the error like this. I am using webpack in my project. This is my Webpack

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        server: './src/server.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    target: 'node',    
    plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/\.\.\/environments\/environment/, '../environments/environment.prod')
    ],
    externals: [nodeExternals({
        whitelist: [
        /^ng2-timeout/
        ]
    })],
    node: {
        __dirname: true
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    }
}
```

While run my project i had error like this 
[image: Error]

Comment: May be your path is incorrect or the specified file is not there in the path..

Comment: browse to your environments folder and check if environment. prod file exists

Comment: @Subburaj  yes changed in the url but having error and also not having the idea where to change the url in the webpack

Comment: @Gautam yes having environment.prod file in my environments folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed that issue by removing this code from the webpack file

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/\.\.\/environments\/environment/, '../environments/environment.prod')
    ],
```